# Issue testing multiple spring cloud stream apps

Tags: spring-integration, spring-test, spring-cloud-stream

Scenario: I have 3 spring cloud streaming apps

- 1'st: unmarshalls XML payload into JAXB object
- 2'nd: Converts JAXB payload into our domain POJO
- 3'rd: Validate domain object

I am trying to test the 3'rd app. I have included the 1'st and 2'nd applications as test dependencies. I have added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now I have about 20 xml files with various validation scenario's. The first test works fine. I am able pick up the expected message of the channel using:

```
    final Message<PaymentInstruction> mceMessage =
            (Message<PaymentInstruction>) collector.forChannel(
                    validationBindings.mce()).take();
```

The 2'nd test that is run is where I have an issue. The test just sits at 'take'.

I have done some digging in the spring-integration-core-4.3.8.jar and have traced the issue to org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher:

```
@Override
public synchronized boolean addHandler(MessageHandler handler) {
    Assert.notNull(handler, "handler must not be null");
    Assert.isTrue(this.handlers.size() < this.maxSubscribers, "Maximum subscribers exceeded");
    boolean added = this.handlers.add(handler);
    if (this.handlers.size() == 1) {
        this.theOneHandler = handler;
    }
    else {
        this.theOneHandler = null;
    }
    return added;
}
```

There is a handler that was added for the first test, so it assigns null to 'this.theOneHandler'

My options are:

- Refactor the code in the other 2 projects so that I can do the unmarshalling and creating of my domain object without the need for the spring cloud app code
- I can create an individual unit test class per test case, however I'd rather not go this route as the startup time for spring boot will be high that will be multiplied by the number of test cases
- Do I have some missing configuration that would allow me to have these multiple handlers or am I breaking the way I want to use spring cloud streaming?

Environment:

- Java 8 Update 131
- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.RELEASE
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

`theOneHandler` is a dispatching optimization used when a channel has only one subscriber.

It sounds like you are binding all your services to the same channel, which is not what you want.

Bottom line is you can't do what you are trying to do because each of the services are using the same channel name (presumably `input`).

You would need to load each service in a separate application context and wire them together with bridges.

**EDIT**

You could also test them using an [aggregated application](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_aggregation).

Comment: You could also use an aggregated app to wire them together.